# How to check if dynamic array is empty?

Tags: c#

This is my code :

```
  var client = new FacebookClient(token);
 dynamic result = client.Get("search?q=tbilisi&type=user", new {  });
```

result.data is an array, how to determine if it's an empty array. For example what i'm trying to do :

```
 while (true)
 {
     if (result == null)
     {
         break;
     }
     if (result.data ==  null )
     {
         break;
     }
```

But not woks. When `result.data = []` i want to check and break while loop.

Comment: Use `result.count` instead of `.length` maybe?

Comment: Same error, it is json array object

Comment: If you *do* know type of object why do you use `dynamic` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var array = result.data as Facebook.JsonArray;
if (array == null || array.Count == 0)
```

Comment: It is dynmic object and doesn't have Length property

Comment: Runtime error :  'Facebook.JsonArray' does not contain a definition for 'Length'

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili so, you have JsonArray object

Comment: Same error , it doesn't have any property, i think need to cast

Comment: I've to use jsonserilizer, but can't figure out how

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili it's not a property, it's a class name

Comment: I've updated code, now it will  be more clear on wich type i am working in

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true)
{
     if (result == null)
     {
         break;
     }
     if (result.data ==  null || !result.data.Any())
     {
         break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while (result.data.length >0)
        {
your code here
            }

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

> if (object == null || ((JArray)object).Count == 0) {
> `// code`
> }